# Using apply function with ff package in R

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, apply, ff

I am trying to apply a given function to the columns in a "as.ffdf" object but I haven't had any luck.  Can anyone provide suggestions to the below?  n = 3711 and myProbDensity has dimensions of 95248 rows and 3711 columns.

```
myDF <- as.ffdf(myProbDensity)
test <- ff(vmode = "double", dim = c(1, n))
test <- apply(myDF, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x)
                                   myQuantileFun(x = as, ex = myDF,
                                                 h = 0.001)
```

When executing the above code I get "you can only change the fastest rotating dim".  I'm not really sure what this means.  Also the myQuantileFun function returns a function and not a value (I'm not sure if this makes a difference). Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you make the question reproducible? Some dummy data, a silly function that does more or less nothing... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for some tips on how to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `apply(myDF,...)` try `apply(myDF[,],...)`